# How to use Border on StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, stackpanel

So, I am trying to develop app in WPF (again). I wanted to have nice, black border with rounded corenrs around my `StackPanel`. In order to do this I have written:

```
<Border x:Name="debugPanel" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <StackPanel Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="#C7C7C7">
        <!--contents-->
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

But the result is ugly :( See below picture:

[image]

**Note that** it even might be wrong way of adding a border, I just figured it out myself. So if you have any recommendations and remarks, I would gladly hear them out as well.

Comment: Give the border the desired background and make the background of the StackPanel transparent.

Comment: @Lennart that was sooo easy... :) If you want, you can exapnd this comment together with sample code to an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the background on the border instead of the StackPanel:

```
<Border x:Name="debugPanel" Background="#C7C7C7" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <StackPanel Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="Transparent">
        <!--contents-->
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```